# divide image without loosing its coordinates (tile)

Tags: python, image, tile, yolo, opencv

I have a large images 5000x3500 and I want to divide it into small images 512x512 but without loosing the original image coordinates. The large images are annotated/labled that's why I want to keep the original coordinates and I will use the small images to train YOLO model. I am not sure if that called tiled or not. but is there any suggestion to do it using python or opencv-python?

Comment: what's your next step after dividing ? are you going to split the labels text file also ?

Comment: That can be done easily in ImageMagick using -crop and saving the tiles as PNG or TIFF where the crop coordinates are kept in meta data. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile

Comment: yes @venkatakrishnan. I want to split the labels text file too. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you @fmw42. I will check that out.